# QUERY LIMIT select specific rows

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

Im trying to find 20.000(starting 5000 rows in) row with a hotmail domain in email, but I not sure what sql are allowed in SFMC. Can anyone give some hints on a solution for this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table LIMIT 5000,20000 
WHERE (substring_index(substr(email, instr(email, '@') + 1),'.',1)) = 'hotmail'
```

EDIT:

Im getting closer now, but it still dosnt work

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT *, Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY cardid) AS row, Substring( [email address],(Charindex('@', [email address])+1),Len( [email address]) - (Charindex('@', [email address]))) AS domain FROM usableusers
 ) a WHERE a.row > 0 AND a.row <= 500 AND a.domain = 'hotmail.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried.

```
Select id, name from table where email like '%hotmail.com'
```

For more details check how to write queries on platform

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm

Comment: I think this is for a Marketing cloud Query activity, so it is T-SQL, not SOQL.

Comment: It looks like LIKE '%hotmail.com' works, now I just need to sort out the "range/row" issue

Comment: Are you just trying to "select top 20000" from the table?  Select top 20000 id, name from table where email like '%hotmail.com'

Comment: My first query would be the first 20000, the next query would then have to find the next 20000(so skip the first 20000)